# Sequelize validations aways returns false

Tags: node.js, validation, express, sequelize.js

I'm creating a model that needs some validations, but the validations handle an error when I input the correct or wrong data.

What is the right way to configure model validations?

My model is:

```
 return sequelize.define('books', {
    id                   : { type: DataTypes.BIGINT   , primaryKey:true, autoIncrement:true },

    isbn_10              : { type: DataTypes.BIGINT   , allowNull: false, 
      validate: { 
        min:10,
        max:10
      } 
    },

    title                : { type: DataTypes.STRING   , allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        isNumeric:true,
        min:2,
        max:255
      }
    }, { underscored    :true, freezeTableName:true});
```

And I'm validation on this way:

```
  models.Book.create(req.body)
          .success(function(book) { console.log(book); res.render('books/create', { books:models.Book }); })
          .error(function(errors) { 
            console.log(errors); 
          });
```

The form input data is:

```
    { Book: 
   { isbn_10: '123123131',
     title: '',
  cadastrar: 'Submit Query' }}
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you show the error please

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved, I update the sequelize version form 2.0.0.alpha.0 to 2.0.0.dev11 and the validations start to work again.

Thanks.